# Detect whether logged user visited page before as unlogged user

Tags: php, authentication

I was wondering whether it is possible to detect that currently logged user visited the page before but not being logged in.

I was thinking of IP, cookies, browser etc, but IP may be changed easily, delete cookies is a piece of cake, also you can change browser.

After some searching and thinking I came up with idea... it is not possible. Even if it was - it would need a quite big database space to do it and would probably be not to hard to deceive.

Is my conclusion right or you have some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is right if you want a 100% accurate result. If you dont mind a few misses then you use cookies.

- Cookies

  - If the cookies is there, 100% accurate that he was there
  - If its not there, the cookies could have been deleted or user is using other browser/device
- IP

  - Never an accurate result, as IP's are shared between users (office buildings, wifi hotspots)
- Finger printing (combine all info you have on a user to identify them)

  - Never an accurate result, but better then just IP.

Comment: I mainly want to avoid cheating by users so cookies are not a good option - just change a browser, just like you wrote.

Comment: tracking unregistered users is just impossible to do with 100% accuracy. Thats why sites require a login to identify somebody :)